# Changing default filesystem in WAR file prepared by Gradle plugin

Tags: gradle, groovy, war, soapui

I would like to deploy a mock service developed with SoapUI. I have SoapUI project, web.xml and now I would like to add them to WAR archive. I'm using Gradle to prepare this WAR file.

My code below:

```
war {
    archiveName 'mock.war'
    webXml file ('src/main/webapp/web.xml')
}
```

Default filesystem of produced archive is:

- META-INF
- WEB-INF

  - lib

    - some libs...
  - classes (this folder I would like to rename to 'soapui')

    - some files...
  - web.xml

Is there any possibility, to change the name of 'classes' folder?
Thanks in advance,
Patryk

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? `classes` is the standard directory.

Comment: I want to change the name of folder - 'classes' is not appropriate.

Comment: what are you going to \keep in that directory?

Comment: soapUI project file

Comment: Have you tried building war file using SoapUI tool?